# In 1 Peter 2:17, who is the king to which he refers, and how, specifically, is he to be honored?

Tags: referent-identification, 1-peter

> [1 Peter 2:17 NKJV] (17) Honor all [people]. Love the brotherhood. Fear God. Honor the king.

Might he be referring to Christ as King?

Or might he be referring to an obligatory sacrifice to the Caesar/Emperor (Nero)?

Answer (score 1):

The Apostle Peter gave four directives, which are brief in expression but broad in implication. He told believers to (1) "honor" (esteem, respect) all men, whether they deserve it or not; (2) "love" (agapate, love much) the "brotherhood, i.e the Christian fraternity): (3) "fear" (phobeisthe, be in awe, revere) God; (4) "honor" esteem, respect) the "king," the sovereign).

Although he directed believers to honor all men, Peter specifically mentioned the king; the language used in his first directive indicates that some men deserve more honor than others. In each of the three latter directives the Greek verb denotes continuous action; believers should keep on loving the brotherhood; they should keep on fearing God; they should keep on honoring the king.

We are to respect the head leader of the country. We may not like him (or her) and may even consider them our enemy. What did Jesus say, "Love your enemies. (Matthew 5:44). Also remember Romans 13:1, "Let every person be in subjection to the governing authorities. For there is no authority except from God, and those which exist are established by God." And no, I did not forget about Jesus Christ. It's a given that He is "Lord of lords and King of kings." Revelation 19:16.